# TinyMCE 4 font toolbar not translated

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization, tinymce

I upgraded my web application to use the latest TinyMCE version 4.0.1. My application is internationalized, so I also updated the language packs.

Everything seems to work correctly and is translated, except for the font selection dropdownlists (fontselect, fontsizeselect, formatselect).

They display: "Font Family", "Font Sizes" and "Paragraph" regardless of the language I initalize TinyMCE with.

This is the init code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            tinymce.init({
                selector: "textarea.tinyMCE",
                skin: "lightgray",
                language: "<%= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName %>",
                plugins: "table,textcolor,link,image,code",
                theme: "modern",
                menubar: false,
                toolbar1: "fontselect,fontsizeselect,formatselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,cut,copy,paste",
                toolbar2: "bold,italic,underline,|,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,alignjustify,|,bullist,numlist,|,removeformat,|,undo,redo",
                toolbar3: "link,unlink,|,image,|,hr,|,code",
                width: 640,
                height: 320,
                media_strict: false,
                forced_root_block: false
            });
        });
    </script>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translations seem to be uncomplete in some areas, you could contribute the corrected translation directly on their translation service:
https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/tinymce/

or edit the language file .js manually for your languages.

Comment: That is odd, because the page says that 100% is translated for German. But I have the same problem for German and the other languages. Adding keys for "Font Family" do solve the problem. A translation for "Paragraph" however is ignored.

Comment: It's the same thing with Swedish, I'll report it in their bug-tracker.

Comment: Great, thank you. It's strange that I am the first to notice this.